# beautiful soup find all p until form

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a website layout as this:

```
<p> section1 </p>
<p> section2 </p>
<pre> section 3 <p> section 4 </p> </pre>
<p> section 5 </p>
<pre> section 6 </pre>
<form> 
<p> section 7 </p>
<textarea> <p> section 8 </p></textarea>
```

I was to get all the text until section 6 (everything before "form" part). However, I can't use findAll('p') because it included everything in the form. Other website also has similar layout but more of less section before "form" part.
I wonder how can i get all the part before section 6 using BeautifulSoup?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the DOM until you find the `form` tag. Something like this:

```
tag = soup.find('p')  # this will give you the first p tag
data = ''
while True:
    if isinstance(tag, bs4.element.Tag):
        if tag.name == 'form':
            break
        else:
            data = data + tag.text  # string concatenation
            tag = tag.nextSibling
    else:
        tag = tag.nextSibling

print data
```

This will give you a output  like this:

```
section2 
section 3  section 4  
section 5 
section 6
```

Comment: really? what is the output/error? did imported it in your script? do `import bs4` in your script.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, it works for when i import bs4. However, instead of print tag.text, is there a way to save all of them in a single variable and print it later?

Comment: Hi, I added the website link above my question. Your code only able to add section 4-6 but it does not included section 1-3. can you please help me to double check

Comment: Hi, it print out the same as before https://pastelink.net/ler I included my code and the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99672/discussion-between-salman-wahed-and-hong-le).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use the [`find_all_previous()`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) method. You can select the `form` element and fetch all the `p` tags before that element.

```
>>> a = soup.form
>>> a.find_all_previous("p")
[<p> section 5 </p>, <p> section 4 </p>, <p> section2 </p>, <p> section1 </p>]
```

Above code can be reduced to

```
soup.form.find_all_previous("p")
```

Comment: Hi, it only works till section 3. I added the website link on my question.

Comment: @HongLe - Could you be more specific? I am able to fetch all the `p` tags before the form from the link that you've provided.

Comment: Hi, I tried as you suggested, however, it only print out until the line:  `public double convertFrom(double toMeasurement) { . . . } ` . The rest of the code is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
soup.form.find_previous_siblings()
```

Here is the output example:

```
In[31]: [x for x in soup.form.find_previous_siblings()]
Out[31]: 
[<pre> section 6 </pre>,
 <p> section 5 </p>,
 <pre> section 3 <p> section 4 </p> </pre>,
 <p> section2 </p>,
 <p> section1 </p>]
```

Comment: Hi, it only get until halfway for this code. I added the website link on my question. I can only get from section 1-3 only.